# JBoss can't find module javax.api

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I just restarted my system today and when I wanted to start JBoss Wildfly I got this error :

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.api:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1050)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1406)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1434)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:385)
```

I had no changes and did just reboot my system.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I think you are missing javax.api dependency...One thing you can do is remove all deployments from wildfly and try restarting

Comment: This does not work, I think it has something to do with JBoss itself